# velocity and position

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to find the position of an object moving along the $x$-axis at $4.0$ seconds.  The function is $V(t) = (2t-t^2)$ m/s.  I have found the acceleration of object at $t = 3.0$ seconds by $A(t) = dv/dt = 2(1-t) = -4$ m/s but don't know how to find the position at certain times.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just calculate $\int {\rm d}t\;v(t)$

Comment: Acceleration is change of velocity with respect to time...  Velocity is change of position with respect to time...  To get Velocity from Acceleration - Integrate.  To get Position from Velocity...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I suppose that you know that, if $s(t)$ is the unction that represents the position as a function of time, than the velocity is defined as
$$
v(t)=\frac{ds(t)}{dt}
$$
so the function $s(t)$is an antiderivative (a primitive) of $v(t)$ . in your case you know $v(t)$ so ,you can find an antiderivative?

Note that this function $s(t)$ is defined  up to a constant, than can be determined from the ''initial conditions'' (e.g. the position  at the time $t=0$).

(Note also that the acceleration is measured in the unit $m/s^2$, not $m/s$)